# exteremely slow moc file generation on clang

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I have a project based on Qt and cmake. I am facing an issue of extremely slow automoc generation while compiling on clang Mac OS X. It runs fine on windows( msvc ) and linux( gcc ). Can you please help me identify possible cause for it , or it's natural to be slow on clang. Some times it takes 20 minutes for generating 10 moc files. I am using Qt 5.5 , though I faced same problem with Qt 5.4 too. I have tried Makefile as well as Xcode , in both the cases , automoc is very slow.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that shows your problem?

Comment: By minimum example , do you mean to create a small cmake project with qt gui components and check if moc file generation is slow in this project too?...

Comment: I don’t see  how moc should be affected by the choice of compilers, as it runs independent, and before, the actual compilation.

Comment: That's true. But I am facing the problem with Qt on clang , that's why I mentioned the compiler here and also I have posted the question under Qt tag and not clang. It's probably the problem with qmake , but it's happening for all the versions of Qt available on my system , and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Can you reproduce the effect when you run the MOC manually from the command line? This could exclude a bunch of errors in your build system.